# How do I modify the RDBMS nested SQL queries into a Hadoop framework using Pig or Hive?

Tags: hive, apache-pig, rdbms

How do I modify the RDBMS nested SQL queries into a Hadoop framework using hive?

Answer (score 0):

No need to modify, nested queries are supported (at least in the FROM clause)